# Allow solr 4.10.3 to listen two interfaces only in solrcloud

Tags: java, solr, jetty, solrcloud

I have to configure solrcloud with two hosts (nodes). For this I cannot run solr on localhost interface. It should be some local ip so that both nodes in solrcloud can connect with each other. I have a third interface that is live IP. I do not allow solr to listen on this live interface. I want solr should listen on local IP and localhost only. How I can change conf. I am using solr 4.10.3 with jetty server. Also command line argument *`-Djetty.host=127.0.0.1`* work for one interface only but not for more than one interface.